# Microscope Camera Driver

Tags: camera

I recently purchased a microscope to help with soldering. As a gift I was given this camera for the microscope but no software. Does anyone know where I can find drivers for this camera?

The camera is not branded and only has "Digital Camera DCE-2" written on the front. Google searches have not come up with any link to download drivers.

[image]

Comment: The vendor ID and product ID are?

Comment: USB VID/PID would go a long way in helping.

Comment: What operating system do you need the drivers for? Also, this question is off-topic on this site. Anyway, see [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-do-i-get-my-usb-digital-microscope-camera-to/01b303df-3454-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) and try the AMcap suggestion there.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same camera, it came with a small cd. However,last week I did not have my laptop with me and the cd program was incompatible with my coworkers laptop. It had Windows 7 and a preinstalled webcam in the middle of the monitor. I just plugged it in, let windows troubleshoot it and search for drivers in the web. It identified it as an Lenovo PC camera (which is not) but it downloaded a driver for it. I opened the webcam program to take pictures, change the camera in use in the program to the Lenovo PC am and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The microscope kit I bought at Amazon came with that camera, and there is a small page with the above address where you can find the drivers:

http://microscopenet.com/Drivers/A1502_64bit.rar

Answer (score -3):

Found answer here.

http://www.afterdawn.com/software/audio_video/capture_video/amcap.cfm

> AMCap is a small yet fully functional video capture application compatible with Microsoft DirectShow.
>
> It is based on the sample AMCap source code from the Microsoft DirectX 9 SDK. AMCap supports still captures to BMP, JPEG and PNG formats and it remembers your Video Input, Video Standard and Video size settings from previous session. It has some nice features like multimonitoring support, zooming, aspect ratio and deinterlacing features

Comment: AMCap is just a video stream viewer, it doesn't provide hardware drivers.